# U/wasy/b/n font shape warning and why does it happen?

Tags: fonts, errors

I got this weird warning after compiling this snippet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
    \setlength{\parindent}{2.30em}
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

% Document dimensions and margins
\usepackage[top=1.8in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.75in, right=1.25in, headheight=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}  % section font size
    \sectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsubsectionfont{\normalsize}
    \paragraphfont{\normalsize}
    \subparagraphfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage{etoolbox}       % remove spaces before and after paragraph
\usepackage{setspace}       % control linespacing
    \setstretch{1.5}

% Pagination
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancyplain} % <- use fancyplain instead fancy
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \addtocounter{page}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

\end{document}
```

It produces the following error.
[image: Error 1]

However, compiling this code snippet doesn't produce an error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
    \setlength{\parindent}{2.30em}
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[top=1.8in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.75in, right=1.25in, headheight=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}  % section font size
    \sectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsubsectionfont{\normalsize}
    \paragraphfont{\normalsize}
    \subparagraphfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % remove spaces before and after paragraph
\usepackage{setspace} % control linespacing
    \setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex} % for APA 7
\addbibresource{References.bib}

%Pagination
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- use fancyplain instead fancy
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\chapterfont{\normalsize \centering \MakeUppercase}

\begin{document} 

\pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \addtocounter{page}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures \newpage
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\end{document}
```

The result of the warning is shown in these images:

With Warning (first snippet):
[image: Bigger Table of Contents font]

Without Warning (second snippet):
[image: Smaller Table of Contents font]

How is this happening? I honestly don't know what is the major difference that triggered the warning. I would rather have the second picture due to thesis requirements. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings. It basically means that there are no bold version of some symbol and that it is using a non-bold version instead. BTW: please always try to minimize your MWE. There is a lot in this MWE that is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I try to add them so that I won't miss something as I can't pinpoint the exact trigger for the warning. Also added clarification as well @daleif to help with visualization. I wanted the output of the second snippet to happen (edited post question to reflect it).

Comment: Keep outcommenting stuff until you identify when it goes away, then investigate

Comment: I get no warning from your document and don't think that it should load wasy. Show your log-file.

Comment: unrelated to your question but the comment here is a completely false description of the package `\usepackage{etoolbox} % remove spaces before and after paragraph`

Comment: The warning you show is not an error and is quite expected if you ask for a wasy symbol in bold, as there is no bold available so it uses normal weight with that warning, but you have not shown any code using the wasy font that would give the warning.

Comment: Here's the pastebin of the log file @UlrikeFischer: https://pastebin.com/jpTLRBVC

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out the false description of the package @DavidCarlisle. Here's the relevant log file of the error: https://pastebin.com/jpTLRBVC

Comment: Oh my bad, @UlrikeFischer. No warning but why the font for the ToC is still large?